# How to parse a date?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse this date with `SimpleDateFormat` and it is not working:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Formaterclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
        String strDate = "Thu Jun 18 20:56:02 EDT 2009";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dateStr = formatter.parse(strDate);
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(dateStr);
        System.out.println("yyyy-MM-dd date is ==>"+formattedDate);
        Date date1 = formatter.parse(formattedDate);

        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        formattedDate = formatter.format(date1);
        System.out.println("dd-MMM-yyyy date is ==>"+formattedDate);
    }
}
```

If I try this code with strDate=`"2008-10-14"`, I have a positive answer. What's the problem? How can I parse this format?

PS. I got this date from a `jDatePicker` and there is no instruction on how modify the date format I get when the user chooses a date.

Comment: For parsing/formatting dates with Java 8, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8/22463063#22463063

Comment: Why is there no method in apache DateUtils which takes in util dates and gives out an integer.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You cannot expect to parse a date with a SimpleDateFormat that is set up with a different format.

To parse your "Thu Jun 18 20:56:02 EDT 2009" date string you need a SimpleDateFormat like this (roughly):

```
SimpleDateFormat parser=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Use this to parse the string into a Date, and then your other SimpleDateFormat to turn that Date into the format you want.

```
        String input = "Thu Jun 18 20:56:02 EDT 2009";
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        Date date = parser.parse(input);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);

        ...
```

JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: having the same issue ... it works good on Java7,   but fails 
on parsing  "Thu Jun ..." as "EEE MMM ..."  in Java6.
  Any ideas ?

Comment: eventuell new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH); could be needed if current locale != ENGLISH

Comment: @jwl how to parce `Sun Dec 06 11:15:00 IST 2015` this date

Comment: What if `Locale` changes not able parse on `4.4 and 5.1` devices

Comment: Note that `SimpleDateFormat` is configured with a `TimeZone` either by default or by calling the `setTimeZone` method. That time zone is used during parsing *if and only if* a time zone is not indicated in the string to be parsed.

Answer (score 53):

The problem is that you have a date formatted like this:

```
Thu Jun 18 20:56:02 EDT 2009
```

But are using a `SimpleDateFormat` that is:

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

The two formats don't agree.  You need to construct a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that matches the layout of the string you're trying to parse into a Date.  Lining things up to make it easy to see, you want a `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
Thu Jun 18 20:56:02 EDT 2009
```

Check the JavaDoc page I linked to and see how the characters are used.

Comment: @eddie how to parce `Sun Dec 06 11:15:00 IST 2015` date to `dd mm yy`

Comment: What if Locale changes not able parse on 4.4 and 5.1 devices

Answer (score 28):

We now have a more modern way to do this work.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is bundled with Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). These new classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. They are a vast improvement over the troublesome old classes, java.util.Date/.Calendar et al.

Note that the 3-4 letter codes like `EDT` are neither standardized nor unique. Avoid them whenever possible. Learn to use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats instead. The java.time framework may take a stab at translating, but many of the commonly used codes have duplicate values.

By the way, note how java.time by default generates strings using the ISO 8601 formats but extended by appending the name of the time zone in brackets.

```
String input = "Thu Jun 18 20:56:02 EDT 2009";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" , Locale.ENGLISH );
ZonedDateTime zdt = formatter.parse ( input , ZonedDateTime :: from );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt : " + zdt );
```

When run.

> zdt : 2009-06-18T20:56:02-04:00[America/New_York]

### Adjust Time Zone

For fun let's adjust to the India time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant ( ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

> zdtKolkata : 2009-06-19T06:26:02+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

### Convert to j.u.Date

If you really need a java.util.Date object for use with classes not yet updated to the java.time types, convert. Note that you are losing the assigned time zone, but have the same moment automatically adjusted to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );
```

Comment: how to parce `Sun Dec 06 11:15:00 IST 2015` date format to `dd mm yyyy` i am not able to parce with `SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)` tried with bot `Z` and `z`

Comment: @SagarHudge Use `DateTimeFormatter` not `SimpleDateFormat`. Reread my Answer.

Comment: The device targeting `4.4 eureka` and `Asus 5.1` having parsing issue on app language change to non English languages like `Marathi/Hindi` normal date able to parse of  `dd mm yyyy`

Comment: @SagarHudge  Specify a `Locale` on the `DateTimeFormatter` to determine the human language and cultural norms used in translation.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter ` targets `26` having issue on `4.4 anf 5.1 device`

Comment: @SagarHudge  For Android <26, see *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 12):

How about [getSelectedDate](http://www.jdatepicker.com/docs/api/com/standbysoft/component/date/swing/JDateComponent.html#getSelectedDate())? Anyway, specifically on your code question, the problem is with this line:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The string that goes in the constructor has to match the format of the date. The documentation for how to do that is [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Looks like  you need something close to "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"

Answer (score 2):

In response to:
"**How to convert Tue Sep 13 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Hora de verano central (México)) to dd-MM-yy in Java?**", it was marked how duplicate

Try this:
With `java.util.Date`, `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, it's a simple solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String fecha = "Tue Sep 13 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Hora de verano central (México))";
    Date f = new Date(fecha);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("-5GMT"));
    fecha = sdf.format(f);
    System.out.println(fecha);
}
```