# Convert string "11-10-10 12:00:00" into Date object

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to parse date in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java)

I want to convert the string `"11-10-10 12:00:00"` into a `Date` object, but I am not able to do so. Can you please help me out?

I have the Date object which has the value "Mon Oct 11 00:00:00 IST 2010"

```
DateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss");    
String strDate = newDateFormat.format(tempDate);  
//**i got strDate as strDate is : 11-10-10 12:00:00**
DateFormat newDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm:ss");    
try {    
 tempDate = newDateFormat1.parse(strDate); 
     // **getting tempDate as - Mon Oct 11 00:00:00 IST 2010**    
   } catch (ParseException e) {    
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block    
 e.printStackTrace();    
 }
```

Comment: What language - it looks like C#. Also this has been asked many times before. Check out the questions under "Related" ->

Answer (score 7):

```
DateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");    
Date d = newDateFormat.parse("11-10-10 12:00:00");
System.out.println(d);
```

Here is [**ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/wFGep)

Comment: Hi Hilal,  thanks for the reply. but your code producing the same output. d= "Mon Oct 11 12:00:00 IST 2010" and i want in "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss" format.

Comment: This code parses the date, as you asked.  Printing it is a whole other issue.  A Date is just a number, and the date and format are not related to each other, so Java will print the date however it pleases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Java code—not my specialty—but I *think* your issue is the "hh" in your format string, which causes `parse` to interpret "12:00:00" as midnight instead of noon. Try changing it to "HH" and see if that parses correctly.

Comment: Hi Dan Tao, i tried with HH too but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CultureInfo for Hindi it is "hi-IN".  For full list of cultures check this link [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getconsolefallbackuiculture.aspx)

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = "11-10-10 12:00:00";

        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(str, new CultureInfo("hi-IN", false));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for your reply but that code seems to be for microsoft and my question for JAVA.