# How to convert java.lang.string To java.util.date in java

Tags: java, date-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to parse date in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java)

I am getting "`Mon Aug 01 00:00:00 IST 2011`" (java.lang.String) as string and i need to convert it to "`01-08-2011`" Date(java.Util.Date) ,how to do this

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/999172/307767

Answer (score 3):

use the SimpleDateFormat class

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

to print the date. This will print the current date in predefined formatted using SimpleDateFormat

```
System.out.println("Current Date " + sdf.format(new Date());

String mydate = "01-08-2011";
```

to convert string into date

```
Date parseDate = sdf.parse(mydate);
```

Comment: Vinay is getting `Mon Aug 01 00:00:00 IST 2011` not `01-08-2011`, use pattern: `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at (`Simple`)`DateFormat`'s `parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29) class in the javadocs.

> Constructs a SimpleDateFormat using the given pattern and the default
>   date format symbols for the default locale

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println("Date " + sdf.format(new Date());
```

Comment: I think "E M d k:m:s z y" would be the correct date format. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html