# Passing javascript date to java

Tags: java, javascript, formatting

I store dates on server side in UTC timezone.
When client (browser) wants to pass some date to server it sends date like

```
"Tue Jan 03 2012 16:50:32 GMT+0400 (Russian Standard Time)"
```

1. Is this format standard across all browsers?
2. If 1. is false, how can I redefine the `Date` format function? Is this a good practice?
3. How can I convert JS `Date`s to a UTC `java.util.Date` with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`?

**UPDATE**

I thought that passing date as formatted string (with timezone part) will cause less headache since I shouldn't bother to convert dates to UTC on client side. So I avoid any date conversions in JS code.

Comment: What does the client code look like? It would be simpler if it could pass the "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" value, which would only need simple integer parsing.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java

Comment: @jon-skeet Please, take a look to my update. Thanks.

Comment: @PlasticRabbit: JavaScript `Date` already knows the UTC milliseconds-since-epoch - it's better *not* to introduce time zones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should send the number of milliseconds since epoch (1 Jan 1970 UTC) that is available via the `+` prefix operator as in `+new Date(2012, 0, 1)`.

Sending anything with a timezone requires both machines to have the same timezone definitions which means you will likely end up with subtle bugs where two dates occurred in one order on one machine but in a different order on another.  You can eliminate that whole class of bugs by using the millis since epoch representation.

To answer your questions:

> Is this format standard across all browsers?

`Date.prototype.toString` and `toUTCString` are both implementation dependent but `toISOString` is reliable.

> http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.43
>
> 15.9.5.43 `Date.prototype.toISOString ( )` # Ⓣ Ⓡ
>
> This function returns a String value represent the instance in time represented by this Date object. The format of the String is the Date Time string format defined in 15.9.1.15. All fields are present in the String. The time zone is always UTC, denoted by the suffix Z. If the time value of this object is not a finite Number a RangeError exception is thrown.
>
> 15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format # Ⓣ Ⓔ Ⓑ
>
> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

Whereas http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.2 says

> 15.9.5.2 `Date.prototype.toString ( )` # Ⓣ Ⓡ
>
> This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are **implementation-dependent**, but are intended to represent the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form.

http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15

> 15.9.5.42 `Date.prototype.toUTCString ( )` # Ⓣ Ⓡ
>
> This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are **implementation-dependent**, but are intended to represent the Date in a convenient, human-readable form in UTC.
>
> NOTE The intent is to produce a String representation of a date that is more readable than the format specified in 15.9.1.15. It is not essential that the chosen format be unambiguous or easily machine parsable. If an implementation does not have a preferred human-readable format it is recommended to use the format defined in 15.9.1.15 but with a space rather than a “T” used to separate the date and time elements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this format is standardized for all browsers.

But you could use the [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) function in JavaScript which returns the milliseconds since `1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC` and initializes the Java [`Date object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) with this value.

Comment: I'm afraid that javascript .getTime() returns value with current timezone adjustment.

Comment: @PlasticRabbit: It shouldn't... when you say you're "afraid" do you mean that you fear the documentation may be incorrect, or you've tried it and seen the wrong values?

Answer (score 1):

You could send the data in [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format, maybe?