# JAVA regex failing

Tags: java, regex, string

I have string which is of format:

`;1=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;2=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;3=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;4=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;`

I have written following code to find string `2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530` from `(;1=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;)`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(;1+)=(\\w+);");

String strFound= "";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strindData);
while (matcher.find()) {
   strFound= matcher.group(2);
}
```

But it is not working as expected. Can you please give me any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've change the input a bit, but just for presentation reasons that is

You can try this:

```
 String input = " ;1=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;   2=2011-10-23T16:17:53+0530;3=2011-10-23T16:18:53+0530;4=2011-10-23T16:19:53+0530;";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(;\\d+?)?=(.+?);");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Can you please give me any hint?

Yes. Neither `-`, nor `:`, nor `+` are part of `\w`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use a regex? Why not call `String.split()` to break up the string on semi-colon boundaries. Then call it again to break up the chunks by the equals sign. At that point you'll have an integer and the date in string form. From there you can [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172) the [date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) string.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public final class DateScan {
    private static final String INPUT = ";1=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;2=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;3=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;4=2011-10-23T16:16:53+0530;";
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        final String[] pairs = INPUT.split(";");
        for (final String pair : pairs) {
            if ("".equals(pair)) {
                continue;
            }
            final String[] integerAndDate = pair.split("=");
            final Integer integer = Integer.parseInt(integerAndDate[0]);
            final String dateString = integerAndDate[1];
            try {
                final Date date = parser.parse(dateString);
                System.out.println(integer + " -> " + date);
            } catch (final ParseException pe) {
                System.err.println("bad date: " + dateString + ": " + pe);
            }
        }
    }
}
```