# Java change date format from custom date to MM dd yyyy

Tags: java, date, parsing, formatting

I am trying to convert a String value that is stored in a database,for example "2012-01-20",  to be in the format January 20, 2012.

I have seen some examples, but they are using `Date` which works with `SimpleDateFormat`.

As an example here is one way I tried but the "try" always fails and the result is null

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date convertedDate=null;

try {

    convertedDate = df.parse(datePlayed);                   

} catch(ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java

Comment: If your dates look like `2012-01-20`, why would you use the format `MM/dd/yyyy` in creating your `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: @JamesMontagne I couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: @JamesMontagne thats not what i actually used that was just the original example i found of one way to do it, your right tho i want month displayed, MMMM.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In short, you're not using the right format for parsing. You need to use **two** `DateFormat` instances; one for parsing and one for formatting.

```
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
Date convertedDate = parser.parse(datePlayed);
String output = formatter.format(convertedDate);
```

Comment: That worked! now i realize what i had to do with setting up the parser first to recognize my pattern. Thank you very much for the fast response

Comment: we can remove the second line and use the parser in 4th line to replace the formatter as parser to make it efficient right?

Answer (score 1):

```
Date da = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd/MM/yyyy !");
System.out.println("Update : " + ft.format(da));
```

You can change your date style do you want at: `E, dd/MM/yyyy !`

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

If the Date is read from a Database, then store it as a java.sql.Date.  You can then use SimpleDateFormat on it, maybe after converting to java.util.Date.  From the ResultSet object, you can extract Dates.

If what you meant is that you are given a date in text that was extracted from a DB by someone else and you are stuck with it.  Try using:

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
 df.setLenient(true);  
 convertedDate = df.parse(datePlayed.trim() );
```

Also try displaying the text you are parsing before you parse to make sure the datePlayed value is what you expect. 
With `parseInt`, an extra space before or after the data will cause an error, so calling `trim()` removes extra spaces.

Comment: Neither of these are the problem.

Comment: Since we didn't see his actual input, we don't know for sure what the problem is. You an I offered solutions to the most likely causes of the problem.

Comment: FYI, [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) is a subclass of [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). No need to convert.