# JSON parse date and time?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Im having a little issue with parsing json date.

Here is what I would like to parse:

```
 {"driver": "247","firstName": "XXXXX","lastName": "XXXXX","lastLatitudeUpdate": "5/21/2012     4:49:17 PM","suspended": "false","checkedin": "0"}
```

I am having trouble parsing "lastLatitudeUpdate" is it because there are spaces in between? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Depends. What is the code you are using to parse it? You can always do a `String.replace("[ ]{2,}", " ");` to replace any double or more space segments. EDIT: I *think* that should work but my regex-foo may be slightly off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Android and therefore working with java (yes you don't mention that, only the tag in your question suggests it...)

Like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java) (and in various other places) you can parse a date in java using the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class:

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:m:s a");
Date d = parserSDF.parse(dateField,0);
```

Of course you have to first parse you json input with some library (e.g. standard library from [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/) or [Google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) and then parse the string you'll get there for the field into a date.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, there is no way for the JSON engine to recognize a string as a Date object.

Long answer:
There is no 'date' type in JSON. However, this JSON is fine, the catch is that lastLatitudeUpdate will be parsed as a string. In order to convert this to a date you should try something like

```
var my_object= JSON.parse({"driver": "247","firstName": "XXXXX","lastName": "XXXXX","lastLatitudeUpdate": "5/21/2012     4:49:17 PM","suspended": "false","checkedin": "0"});
my_object.lastLatitudeUpdate= Date.parse(my_object.lastLatitudeUpdate)
```

This function will give a timestamp. However, you have to make sure the string is correctly recognized, you may have to do some extra work.

Comment: the question is about android and therefore java. nobody ever mentioned javascript... ;)

Comment: @s1lence JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. What is true for javascript is true in any language, in this case. 
Have you even read my answer?

Comment: yes I did. I see your argument about json not having a date type and it's totally correct. However this wasn't the question.Further on Javascript allows a slightly better version of JSON than the real json specification does. (e.g. no quotes needed around string keys)

Answer (score 0):

Some links for hints

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=406

Answer (score -2):

How are you parsing the date? In Chrome this seems to work fine:

```
new Date("5/21/2012     4:49:17 PM");
Mon May 21 2012 16:49:17 GMT-0400 (US Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: In Chrome? This question is about Android. See the tags.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that I am woroking with Java. These are all quick replies! s1lence's answer worked out for me. I never knew there was such a class. Thanks again!