# How to convert "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012" to 18/06/2012?

Tags: java, date

I have a value like the following `Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012` and I want to convert this to `18/06/2012`

How to convert this?

I tried this method

```
public String toDate(Date date) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date theDate = null;
        //String in = date + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        try {
            theDate = dateFormat.parse(date.toString());
            System.out.println("Date parsed = " + dateFormat.format(theDate));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dateFormat.format(theDate);
    }
```

but it throws following exception :

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012"`

Comment: See related section in this page

Comment: @Kazekage Gaara you can see my edit now, let us hope whether you know the answer.

Comment: Agree with Tony, instead of voting great comment you people can try to answer if not let others to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date)

Comment: @SAR same issue I am facing please help

Comment: @SagarHudge Please check the accepted answer and that really solved my issue

Comment: Modern comment: This question was asked 10 years ago, and back then we used `Date`. We should not anymore. No matter if having a `Date`, an `Instant`, a `LocalDate` or some other date-time type, there is no need to format to a string and parse back. Also no date-time object holds a format, so formatting into a string is what you need and all you need. If you nevertheless get an old-fashioned `Date`, the modern solution is `date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I hope following program will solve your problem

```
String dateStr = "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr);
System.out.println(date);        

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
String formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" +         cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println("formatedDate : " + formatedDate);
```

Comment: I think the format for the _dateStr_ example should be: SimpleDateFormat("**EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy**")

Comment: The code is working fine but it should be z and not Z.

Comment: @Pascal i am following same format but not able to parce `("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy") `

Comment: The OP already had a `Date`. This answer assumes that one is calling `date.toString()` (as in the question) and parses the resulting string back into a `Date`. A needless detour, and error-prone too. Also you shouldn’t "hand format" your date. Use a formatter (nowadays that would be a `DateTimeFormatter`).

Answer (score 8):

## java.time

The modern approach is with the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. These supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Parse as a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
String input = "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" )
                                       .withLocale( Locale.US );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Extract a date-only object, a `LocalDate`, without any time-of-day and without any time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
DateTimeFormatter fLocalDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
String output = ld.format( fLocalDate) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt );
System.out.println( "ld: " + ld );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

> input: Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012
>
> zdt: 2012-06-18T00:00+03:00[Asia/Jerusalem]
>
> ld: 2012-06-18
>
> output: 18/06/2012

See this [code run live in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/nBDdXP).

## Poor choice of format

Your format is a poor choice for data exchange: hard to read by human, hard to parse by computer, uses non-standard 3-4 letter zone codes, and assumes English.

Instead use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats whenever possible. The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating date-time values.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). For example, your use of `IST` may be Irish Standard Time, Israel Standard Time (as interpreted by java.time, seen above), or India Standard Time.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

Just need to add: new SimpleDateFormat("bla bla bla", Locale.US)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    java.util.Date fecha = new java.util.Date("Mon Dec 15 00:00:00 CST 2014");
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.US);
    Date date;
    date = (Date)formatter.parse(fecha.toString());
    System.out.println(date);        

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    String formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + 
            (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + 
            "/" +         cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    System.out.println("formatedDate : " + formatedDate);
}
```

Comment: How does this add value beyond the [already accepted two year-old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11097520/642706)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a formula in excel in order to convert this type of date to a date type excel can read: 
`=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(MID(A1,8,3),MID(A1,4,4),RIGHT(A1,4)))`

And you get: `12/7/2016` from: `Wed Dec 07 00:00:00 UTC 2016`

Comment: This Question is about Java programming, not  Microsoft Excel spreadsheets.

Answer (score -2):

A more convenient way will be

```
try {
            String dateToBeFormatted ="Tue Dec 09 00:00:00 IST 1997";
            
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
            DateFormat formatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-YYYY");
            
            Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateToBeFormatted);
            String finalDate = formatTo.format(date);
            System.out.println(finalDate);
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I think you are answering a different question. The OP already had a `Date`, so does not need parsing. That said, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are now long outdated and the latter notoriously troublesome, it is never convenient to use it.

Comment: Two bugs in your code: (1) When running in my time zone, Europe/Copenhagen, I got `12-08-1997`, one day too early. (2) Upper case `YYYY` is wrong. In this case it gives the expected output. With `Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 1997` I got `12-31-1998`, it is one year off. All in all your answer isn’t so helpful as you had intended it. Allow me to suggest that you either delete it or fix the issues.