# Java SimpleDateFormat parsing mystery

Tags: java, date, format

I'm unable to correctly parse a date.....

Here is the code :

```
String UpdateDateFormat = "Fri Mar 06 00:00:00 CET 2015";

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");

try{
     Date UpdateDateFormated = sdf2.parse(UpdateDateFormat);
}
catch(ParseException ex){
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

I get an exception, "Unparseable date..."

I saw this post : [How to convert "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012" to 18/06/2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097256/how-to-convert-mon-jun-18-000000-ist-2012-to-18-06-2012) but it's not working for me.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Just needed to add the Locale.US.