# Convert timestamp to simple date in Java and add to ParseObject

Tags: java, date, parse-platform, simpledateformat, parse4j

**Not Duplicate:** I intended for this question to address the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` that is thrown when attempting to add a formatted date back to a `ParseObject` for rendering purposes.

I've got a list of dates which I want to display in a more readable format when I render them to my page. i.e. I want `Wed Mar 29 13:32:35 CEST 2017` to become `Wed Mar 29`.

```
for (ParseObject requestObject: requestsArrayList) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(sdf.format(requestObject.getDate(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_DATE_REQUESTED)));
        log.info(String.valueOf(date));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    requestObject.add(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_DATE_REQUESTED, date);
}
requestObject.add(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_DATE_REQUESTED, date);
```

I thought `SimpleDateFormat` would be enough but I can't ditch the additional timestamp info and add the object back to my collection. What should I do?

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not implemented!
    at org.parse4j.operation.AddOperation.apply(AddOperation.java:26) ~[parse4j-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.parse4j.ParseObject.performOperation(ParseObject.java:375) ~[parse4j-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.parse4j.ParseObject.addAll(ParseObject.java:301) ~[parse4j-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.parse4j.ParseObject.add(ParseObject.java:296) ~[parse4j-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.nnit.automation.controller.IndexController.findRequestsByCurrentUser(IndexController.java:117) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.nnit.automation.controller.IndexController.findRequestsByCurrentUser(IndexController.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097256/how-to-convert-mon-jun-18-000000-ist-2012-to-18-06-2012

Comment: What result are you getting with SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: The log spits out the same date format. Maybe I'm confused about what I want. I just want to remove the timestamp and timezone from the date: ``2017-04-07 12:08:33.637  INFO 224456 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] com.test.date.WebApplication    : Wed Mar 29 00:00:00 CEST 2017``. Seems like I already have SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: You seem to be logging the result of `Date.toString()`. A `Date` object *just* represents a point in time - it doesn't know about a time zone or format. If you want to log the `Date` in a particular format, you need to do the formatting *when you log*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert "Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 IST 2012" to 18/06/2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097256/how-to-convert-mon-jun-18-000000-ist-2012-to-18-06-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can always convert the date to string in the needed format and add to requestObject

**Sample Updated**

```
for (ParseObject requestObject: requestsArrayList) {
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd");
String date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.format(requestObject.getDate(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_DATE_REQUESTED));
    log.info(String.valueOf(date));
} catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
requestObject.add(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_DATE_REQUESTED, date);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a ``java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 24 18:27:07 CET 2017"`` with this one...

Comment: Here ``Wed Mar 29 00:00:00 CEST 2017``

Comment: Okay so this definitely formats the date correctly, i.e. ``Fri Apr 14`` but it gives ``java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not implemented!`` when I try to add it back to the object. Do you have any idea why that would happen?

Comment: It may mean that requestObject.add(<StringObject>, <StringObject>) method is not implemented. Could you please give a little more context. Where this code is used, Are you trying to call an api, any specific frameworks used.

Comment: I'm using the library Parse4J. Here is the ParseObject that I'm iterating over: https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/parse4j/ParseObject.java

Comment: I suppose Parse only handles one kind of Date format. Maybe I need to create a local POJO and add a new getter for the formatted date...

Comment: Good that you found the solution. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd", Locale.US);

    String date = outputDate.format(inputDate.parse(input.replace("CEST ","")));


} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```