# I want to change date format with given time zone. I have tried it with SimpleDateFormat but still failed

Tags: java, android, date, date-format, date-conversion

The date is  `Wed Jun 21 14:14:23 GMT+08:00 2017` and I want to convert it into `2017-06-21`.

Here is my code:

```
String date = "Wed Jun 21 14:14:23 GMT+08:00 2017";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMMM dd HH:mm:ss 'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = null;
try {
    d = sdf.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: failed in which way.. Show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097256/how-to-convert-mon-jun-18-000000-ist-2012-to-18-06-2012

Comment: thanks for quick response @Rameshbabu  let me check this link

Comment: Great man  that was what i want .. @Rameshbabu

Comment: post your answer. So that it will be helpful for others..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend you to stop using the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. They're outdated, [full of bugs and design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and being replaced by the new date/time API.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To parse the `String` you want, just create a `DateTimeFormatter` and set the `java.util.Locale` to English, to make sure that weekdays and month names (in your case, `Wed` and `Jun`) are parsed correctly. If you don't set a locale, the system's default will be used (and if the default is not English, it won't work).

```
String date = "Wed Jun 21 14:14:23 GMT+08:00 2017";
// create formatter (using English locale to make sure weekdays and month names are parsed correctly)
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
// parse local date
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(date, fmt);
System.out.println(dt.toString()); // 2017-06-21
```

The output is:

> 2017-06-21

Answer (score 0):

Try this works perfect

```
String  formatDate = "Wed Jun 21 14:14:23 GMT+08:00 2017";
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" , Locale.ENGLISH);
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = dateTimeFormat.parse(formatDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String format = dateFormat.format(date);

        Log.d("===========>>>>>",format);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it works as you want.

```
String input_date = "Wed Jun 21 14:14:23 GMT+08:00 2017";
SimpleDateFormat fromthis = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat tothis = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = null;
try {
       date = fromthis.parse(input_date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
String result = tothis.format(date);
System.out.println(result);
```

Input: Wed Jun 21 14:14:23 GMT+08:00 2017

Output: 2017-06-21

Thank you.