# how to convert Tuesday , December 25th, 1900 into MM/dd/yyyy format in java

Tags: java, date

I have date string like Tuesday , December 25th, 1900, how can I covnert it into **MM/dd/yyyy** format. I have refereed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097256/how-to-convert-mon-jun-18-000000-ist-2012-to-18-06-2012) link but with a workaround for my date format.
Below is what I tried but I'm getting an exception as `Unparsable date`.

```
String caseDate = "Tuesday , December 25th, 1900";
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd Z yyyy");
Date date = inputFormat.parse(caseDate);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
Utils.logtMsg("formattedDate "+formattedDate);
```

**Exception as**

> Exception ::: Unparseable date: " Tuesday , December 25th, 1900"

Comment: There might be an issue because of the etra space after your tuesday. Try this String caseDate = "Tuesday , December 25th, 1900";
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE , MMMM dd Z yyyy");

Comment: Please refer this url https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.journaldev.com/17899/java-simpledateformat-java-date-format/amp

Comment: how does your input format match the input string? I mean, did you compare the pattern to the string? `Z` is timezone, multiple commas, etc

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that your input string does not match your input format. I changed the format and it is working fine. Try,

```
String caseDate = "Tuesday , December 25th, 1900";
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE , MMMM dd'th', yyyy");
        Date date = inputFormat.parse(caseDate);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Comment: I cannot remove the th from the string as this is the actual date I'm receving

Comment: I updated my code. Please check now.

Comment: Yes..thanks a lot..saved my day.

Comment: No Problem. Accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Won’t work for `23rd`, though.

Comment: @Ole V.V. how can you convert dates like Tuesday , December 25th, 1900 this in java .time, please refer link for solutions

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi Combine the pieces from your question and the answers to the linked original questions: `LocalDate.parse("Tuesday , December 25th, 1900", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE , MMMM d['st']['nd']['rd']['th'], uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH))`.

Comment: ..and the pieces grabbed..works perfectly! thanks @OleV.V.