# Parse string to get date and time in a specific format in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clj-time

I just started to play with [wit/duckling](https://duckling.wit.ai/). It is written in Clojure and I have no previous experience in Clojure. I need to parse a string like **2016-08-14T19:45:48.000+05:30** to a format like **1945hrs, Sunday, August 14th 2016**. I searched on Internet and came across to lib [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time). After struggling with it for a long time I came across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129760/converting-strings-into-dates-in-clojure) and thought that **rfc822** is my cup of tea. So I used formatter rfc822 but it is giving me exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-08-16T00:00:00.000+05:30"`

Here is my code:

```
(ns firstproj.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [duckling.core :as p])
  (:require [clj-time.format :as f]))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot."
  [x]
  (p/load! { :languages ["en"]})
  (def var_ (p/parse :en$core x [:time]))
  (def date_string "2016-08-14T19:45:48.000+05:30")
  (f/parse (f/formatters :rfc822) date_string))
```

So can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here. Or any other way in Clojure to get my desired date-time format. As I am completely naive in Clojure, I request you to answer in detail, it will help me to understand this in a better way. Thank You.

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: @SamEstep  yes, I am using Java 8.

Comment: OK, great; in that case, I believe my answer is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without actually checking which predefined formatter matches your date format you might just call:

```
(f/parse "2016-08-14T19:45:48.000+05:30")
;; => #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x1bd11b14 "2016-08-14T14:15:48.000Z"]
```

It will try all predefined formatters and return parsed value from the first one that succeeds.

Then to print in your custom format:

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as t])

(def my-time-zone (t/time-zone-for-offset 5 30))

(def my-formatter
  (f/formatter
    "HHmm'hrs', EEEE, MMMM dd yyyy"
    my-time-zone))

(f/unparse my-formatter some-date)
;; => "1945hrs, Sunday, August 14 2016"
```

Unfortunately to my knowledge JodaTime doesn't handle things like adding *st*, *nd*, *rd*, *th* to days.

Comment: I have updated my answer. By default dates are parsed and unparsed using UTC so the previous output was printed for UTC.

Answer (score 7):

The [`clj-time`](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) library is a wrapper for [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). If you're using Java 8, you should prefer the built-in [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library over Joda-Time, for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29750221/5044950). In Clojure, you can use the [Clojure.Java-Time](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time) library, which wraps `java.time`. First, add it to your dependencies:

```
[clojure.java-time "0.2.1"]
```

Then you can use the [`offset-date-time`](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time#zoned-dates) and [`format`](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time#an-appetizer) functions in the `java-time` namespace:

```
(require '[java-time :as time])

(->> (time/offset-date-time "2016-08-14T19:45:48.000+05:30")
     (time/format "HHmm'hrs', EEEE, MMMM d y"))
;;=> "1945hrs, Sunday, August 14 2016"
```

As @Piotrek pointed out in his answer, Joda-Time doesn't seem to support the "th" in your original question. Judging from the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) docs, neither does `java.time`.