# To get Date witout time stamp in java

Tags: java, mysql

How can i get a date instance without a time stamp in java? 
Ex: 2013-05-23( date instance)

Comment: format your date with `yyyy-MM-dd` format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Calendar object to store the date, clear out the time fields, and then get the resulting date:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateYouWantToTruncate);
cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
Date dateOnly = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print out the date use this:

```
    DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

or

```
    DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
```