# Cast string to Date error for return type -ClassCastException

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

I having method that i move type object (in this time type object is type **String**)
and i want to cast it to type date how should i do that .
when i use the following code i getting error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

Code:

```
} else if (typeName.equals("Date")) {

    return new SwitchInputType<Date>((Date) memberValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
final SimpleDateFormat parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

final Date date;
try{ 
    date = parsedDate.parse(stringValue); 
} catch(Exception e) {
    // handle the exception.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to parse a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java)

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = parserSDF.parse(memberValue);
```

Comment: i have tried your code and getting this error :The method parse(String) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: Date date = parserSDF.parse((String)memberValue);

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply cast a `String` to a `Date`. To get a `Date` from a `String` object which has the `String` representation of `Date`, use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

**E.g:**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //Change format according to your needs.
Date date = new Date();
try{
    date = sdf.parse((String)memberValue); //Update:- memberValue.toString() will also work.
}catch(ParseException pe){
    //Do something on Exception.
}
return new SwitchInputType<Date>(date);
```

Comment: I was tried your code but im getting error in the parse :date = sdf.parse(memberValue); the error is :The method parse(String) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (Object),any idea?

Comment: that means the memberValue is of type `Object` and not `String`, hence you need to cast your `memberValue` to `String`. But before that can you just tell what's value present in `memberValue`?

Comment: yes I write that member value is object that now its represnt as string with value 2012-12-03

Answer (score 1):

If its a string, you need to parse it. Try using SimpleDateFormat with appropriate format.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create new date object like this `Date date = new Date(long)` or if you created this string using Date class use its static method `Date.valueOf(String s)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert the string to date object before assigning to a Date. Use SimpleDateFormat.parse() method to parse the string to a Date object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
return new SwitchInputType<Date>(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(memberValue));
```

Comment: I have used your code and im getting this error: he method parse(String) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (Object),any idea?

Comment: Then menmberValue is not a String class object. Can you please verify?