# Converting String to Date object

Tags: java, android

Am trying to store a date object in Android.I want to get the date as a String from `EditText` and then "convert" or should i say store it as a `Date` object.This is what i have done.

I have a `TextField`

```
`EditText dateOfBirthTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DoBTextField);`
```

and then a String

```
`String dateOfBirth = dateOfBirthTextField.getText().toString();`
```

Now i have a `Student` class that has a `dateOfBirth` field of type `Date` and a method

```
`setDateOfBirth(Date dob){
 this.dateOfBirth=dob;
 }
```

How do i set the value of `dateOfBirth` with what ever is entered into `dateOfBirthTextField`?

Comment: Why don't you use a [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) instead of over-complicating with an `EditText`? The user experience is enriched and your life is easier!

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date

Comment: Because enriching user experience is so mainstream :D

Comment: @gunar am just working on something little with this.I just gave `DatePicker` a look and i think it makes more sense.

Comment: Remember SimpleDateFormat construction is expensive, many had performance issue with it. And secondly it is not Thread Safe so use wisely! in your case I would go with DatePicker if UI allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse (yourStringDate);
```

then call

```
setDateOfBirth(date);
```

You can provide your custom format to constructor.

Take a look at SimpleDateFormat javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: the native sqllite database only supports string so you'll probably be saving a string.  So once its validated as a date save the data in the format @mserioli has provided.

Comment: Possibly @mserioli its an ORM (I had to look ORM up)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.dateOfBirth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateOfBirthTextField);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String dateOfBirth = dateOfBirthTextField.getText().toString();
SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // use your pattern here
Date d = s.parse(dateOfBirth);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do sthg like that;

```
 String str = "26/08/1994";
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");                         
 Date date = formatter.parse(str);
```

please notice the capital M.

Answer (score 1):

[click here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/) to see an example by mkyong

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you meant to declare a string `dateOfBirthString` and a date `dateOfBirth`.
You just convert the string to a date with a `SimpleDateFormat`.

It should be something like this:

```
EditText dateOfBirthTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DoBTextField);
String dateOfBirthString = dateOfBirthTextField.getText().toString();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //you have to enter the format of your string, here "dd/MM/yyyy" = "day/month/year"
Date dateOfBirth = sdt.parse(dateOfBirthString);
setDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
```