# Parse a date string stored in Excel file

Tags: java, date, formatting, simpledateformat

I'm not able to parse the date stored in an Excel file.
My code snippets is as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date parsed = format.parse(row.getCell(1).toString());
Date jdate = format.parse(row.getCell(4).toString());
```

My error is:

> Cannot parse the date 08-Jun-2012.

In Excel file the date is stored as 08-06-2012. But it takes it as 08-Jun-2013.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date?rq=1

Comment: What is your expected format,after parsing ?

Answer (score 0):

check the date format in your excel file. It might be DD-Mmm-YYYY. by changing it to DD-MM-YYYY you could parse i guess.

Answer (score 0):

## Make Strings Explicit

When debugging, tear apart complex statements to verify the pieces. In this case, move those row getter calls to separate lines, assigning the values to String variables.

## Be Careful With Formatters

You need to carefully study the doc for formatters, and then double-check the pattern characters.

In your case:

- The format "dd-MM-yyyy" is for month as digits
- The format "dd-MMM-yyyy" is for month as text (name of month)

### Example Code

```
String inputDigits = "08-06-2012";
String inputChars = "08-Jun-2013";

java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatDigits = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatChars = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MMM-yyyy" );

java.util.Date dateDigits = null;
java.util.Date dateChars = null;
try {
    dateDigits = formatDigits.parse( inputDigits );
    dateChars = formatChars.parse( inputChars );
} catch ( ParseException ex ) {
    Logger.getLogger( App.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
}
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateDigits: " + dateDigits );
System.out.println( "dateChars: " + dateChars );
```

When run…

```
dateDigits: Fri Jun 08 00:00:00 PDT 2012
dateChars: Sat Jun 08 00:00:00 PDT 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String dat="08-Jun-2013";
        SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        java.util.Date dt=format.parse(dat);        
        System.out.println("Parsed Date :: "+dt);
    }
```

Its showing -  Sat Jun 08 00:00:00 IST 2013

Use `dd-MMM-yyyy` instead of `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Hope it will help you.