# Date format conversion from 'Tue May 20 00:00:00 PKT 2014' to 20-05-2014

Tags: java, date, datepicker

I have date in this format `Tue May 20 00:00:00 PKT 2014` which I want to convert to `20-05-2014`.

I take this value from an ADF inputDate component. Please help.

Comment: Read `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date)

Comment: I downvoted this question because date formatting and conversion is _extensively_ documented on the open web and just any elementary search with reasonable keywords on any search engine will return code samples. Many hits will also link back to SO. Also this is the kind of questions that just clutter SO and esp. the `Java` tag and show little if no effort on OP's part to do basic research. This question should be closed.

Comment: @BalusC I suppose one kind feeds the other. Poor Monday so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one along with your locale using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29)

```
// Locale for Pakistan region
Locale aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setRegion("PK").build();

// Tue May 20 00:00:00 PKT 2014
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", aLocale);
Date date = format.parse("Tue May 20 00:00:00 PKT 2014");

// 20-05-2014
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", aLocale);

System.out.println(format1.format(date));
```

output:

```
20-05-2014
```

Comment: See, now that's a good answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this util method,

```
static public String getDateInDDMMYY(Date date) throws ParseException{

    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String _24HoursFTimeToConvert = formatter.format(date);

         SimpleDateFormat _24HourSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
         SimpleDateFormat _12HourSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

         Date _24HourDt = _24HourSDF.parse(_24HoursFTimeToConvert);

        return _12HourSDF.format(_24HourDt);
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so that gets the output, but how about parsing the original `String` value?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Input is in Date not String, so parsing is not required here.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm reading the input as `String` - question lacks context, my bad