# Date parsing not working

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am storing date in my DB, before I am taking date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format, I am taking data from user using textbox. But now I want time as well so I am taking date from user and time automatically attaching with user inputted date.

I am getting `date + time` like :

```
05/07/2014 8:55:3.522
```

I have used following code to parse this date and store it into DB, I want to store date in following format :

```
2014-05-07 8:55:3.522 // here format is YYYY-MM-DD and time
```

Code :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(getCheckOutDate());
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
```

I am confused that how to parse received date and change it's format and save into DB.

When I try above code it doesn't parse date.

Any guidance on it.
Thank You.

Comment: is your date field in mysql also of timestamp type?

Comment: Yes field is `Timestamp` and it's in `Postgresql`.

Comment: Why in the world do you have this tagged under java AND javascript??

Comment: Because I am generating date in JavaScript by getting current time instance and user inputted date.

Comment: if you are using preparedstatement then you can use (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int, java.sql.Timestamp))

Comment: Then you need to state that in your question, and provide code if it is relevant. Your question asks specifically about Java date parsing and makes no mention of javascript nor does it make any reference to it. Therefore it is an inappropriate use of the tag.

Comment: @JqueryLearner : No I am using Hibernate for to store data.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to post the relevant codes of hibernate and use hibernate tag

Comment: @ElGavilan - Yes that's my mistake that't why I have removed that tag.

Comment: @user3145373ツ Then why did you you reject two incoming edits that removed it?

Comment: Yes that also my mistake sir. so means you have down voted !!

Comment: Possible duplicate : Have you checked the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date?rq=1)?

Comment: @Keugyeol - from which angle do you think this is a duplicate one ? Have seen whole code ? what my problem is and what in that question...

Comment: @user3145373ツ What I meant by linking the other answer was, have you tried using exact format for the input SimpleDateFormat, and using another format for the output.

Comment: @Keugyeol : Yes I have so many format and then I don't get solution then I have posted to STO, I never directly post question without trying byself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parseDate takes the date to **be** parsed as a string in the format specified. Your format is for the destination, which doesn't matter, as JDBC will take care of that for you.. What you need is something like (untested):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy k:mm:ss.SSSS");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(getCheckOutDate());
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
```

I do hope that helps.

Comment: Sir, here `k` for what ? Can't we have to use `hh` ?

Comment: Sir, it is in the linked javadocs, 'hh' has zero padding, 'kk' has space padding.