# A getter for JTextfield, as date

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, getter

I am  trying to make a getter for a JTextfield, the code looks like this

```
public Date getStartDate() {

    return textFieldStartDate.getText();
}
```

I get the error

```
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Date
```

The problem is obvious, however i dont know how to solve it. I have been searching alot, but couldnt find a simple answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date

Comment: Of course you are having a `Date` field so the return type should be `Date` as well but you are returning `String`. You just need to convert the String to Date and return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Date getStartDate() {
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(textFieldStartDate.getText());
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect. However i changed the format to MM-dd-yyyy, but it results ex. ""Oct 1, 2014 12:00:00 AM" and i want it in ex. "1-10-2014". Why is that not working? btw thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

change your method to

```
    public Date getStartDate() {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date textDate= formatter.parse(textFieldStartDate.getText());
    return textDate;
    }
```

Comment: please provide an explanation of how this works/what you changed.

Comment: Nothing different from above answer.we posted answer at the sametime.