# Java- formatted input

Tags: java

How can I accept input from STDIN in the format
**HH:MM:SSAM**
**here in place of AM , PM can also be there**
and display output in the form **HH:MM:SS**

Comment: by checking if the input format is `HH:MM:SSAM` and using the formatter provided by the java Library to pass the date into a different format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java. And, welcome to stackoverflow! Please check the FAQ [ask] on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. You should at least have tried something yourself and ideally show some **code** of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably be to parse it to a `LocalTime`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa");
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("10:20:05PM", fmt);
System.out.println("time = " + time); //22:20:05
```

Note: the `a` in the format is for [AM/PM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: thanks, if I want to perform an operation hh+12 manually how to do that.. as here it is being done automatically

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "perform an operation hh+12 manually"...

Comment: I need to add 12 to the HH value if the input time is PM

Comment: @M.L. My example already does that...

Comment: yeah I saw that but in the example provided by you, it is done automatically but if we want it to be done manually then??

Comment: @M.L If you mean that you are not allowed to use a built-in class like LocalTime, then you need to parse the string manually and manipulate the content.