# Getting wrong date '01:00:00' when using SimpleDateFormat.parse()

Tags: java, date, datetime

I got wrong result when using `SimpleDateFormat.parse()`.
Code here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String format = "yyyyMMdd";
        String date = "19890416";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        java.util.Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
        System.out.println("date2 = " + date2);
        System.out.println("Locale.getDefault() = " + Locale.getDefault());
}
```

result:

```
date2 = Sun Apr 16 01:00:00 CDT 1989
Locale.getDefault() = zh_CN
```

there is my question:
why in the result it shows up `01:00:00`, instead of `00:00:00`?

What should I do if I want `00:00:00`?

Anyone can help? Thanks!

Update:
I want to know, when define format as "yyyyMMdd", why the default hour shows up "01", thanks.

Comment: I updated the question, please help,thanks

Comment: You are using outmoded old legacy classes. Use java.time instead, [as seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33060590/642706).