# Java - || and && in the if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm trying to do some validation for a user entered date. Is there a way to have multiple `||` statements and then an encompassing `&&` statement for them all? Here's my code:

```
if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 && day < 31 && day > 0)
```

As of right now the `&&` statements only apply to the `month == 11` variable. Is there an easy fix to using `&&` in this if statement (without having to copy/paste it after every variable)?

Comment: Yes, parentheses.

Comment: Yuck. There are better ways of checking if a date is actually valid. How will you handle leap years for example?  Or wierd months like 1752 in England. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date

Comment: I don't agree with the downvotes. It may be a trivial question to most programmers, but other than that there's not much wrong with it. It's to the point, clear and concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use parentheses:

```
if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && day < 31 && day > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parentheses to force precedence.

`if((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && day < 31 && day > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (day < 31 && day > 0))
```

Brackets are your friend

Answer (score 0):

One set of parentheses around all the month || statements will achieve that.

```
if ( (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 ) && day < 31 && day > 0)
```

Now it evaluates as `if(month4,6,9,11 && day<31 && day>0)`

Answer (score -1):

if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (day < 31 && day > 0))