# How to remove the last characters from a string array?

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I have a String ArrayList filled with dates + time. The format is: "11 04 2017 - 12:45:54"
I would like to change the format so it only shows the date: "11 04 2017" and save it to another array.
How can i cut the last few characters of an array?

```
package com.example.hodor.stringcut;
```

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText textView, textView1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    ArrayList<String> listDate = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listDate1 = new ArrayList<>();

    listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:32:45");
    listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:35:45");
    listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:36:45");
    listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:38:45");
    listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:30:45");

    textView.setText(listDate[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < listDate.length; i++) {

        listDate1[i] = listDate[i].substring(0, listDate[i].length(), -10);
        textView.setText(listDate1[1]);
    }
}
```

}

Anybody can help me please?

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. cannot resolve method substring / length. im using java.

Comment: could i maybe only miss a import or does substring and length wont work on array?

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the code? What is the type of "listDate"? How is it instantiated?

Comment: ArrayList<String> listDate = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: do i need to import a method in order to use length and substring?

Comment: Please modify your question to include the portion of the code that includes that list initialization.

Comment: Assuming these Strings are strictly formatted in this manner you could look at `String.substring` and combine that with a loop that iterates over collections.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial `substring(0, length - 11)` concept was correct. You're simply having a problem with types.

`listDate` is of type [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). The [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method isn't applicable for it. It's applicable for its elements which are [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) types.

You're also mixing up the [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) type with [java primitive arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Here's some example of [how to utilize an ArrayList](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist/).

But once you comfortable with that, this code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date = "10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:30:45";
    String modifiedDate = date.substring(0, date.length() - 10);
    System.out.println(modifiedDate);
}
```

Gives an output of...

> 10 - 07 - 2017

At a higher level, if what you're trying to do is parse dates then the link Brandon shared will be much more apt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me

```
package com.example.hodor.stringcut;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText textView, textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        ArrayList<String> listDate = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> listDate1 = new ArrayList<>();

        listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:32:45");
        listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:35:45");
        listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:36:45");
        listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:38:45");
        listDate.add("10 - 07 - 2017 - 12:30:45");

        textView.setText(listDate.get(1));

        for (int i = 0; i < listDate.size(); i++) {
            String date = listDate.get(i);
            listDate1.add(date.substring(0, date.length() -11));

        }
        textView.setText(listDate1.get(1));
    }
}
```