# Fastest way to parse String from java.util.Date

Tags: java, date

I need to convert big amounts of java.util.Date objects to String,
for now I am using

```
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).format(value);
```

but it requires create a new SimpleDateFormat object each time.

What is the fastest way to parse a String in needed format in a big
 amounts without creating new SimpleDateFormat objects, for example yyyy-MM-dd pattern from java.util.Date?

I am using java 7. Solutions from java 8 are not acceptable for me

Comment: Is there a slow way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should provide what you have tried which is slower

Comment: If you are processing large number of `Date` serially, creating a single instance would work (provided they use the same format). If you are trying to do the conversion parallelly, then you would have to create a new instance for each conversion.

Comment: I wonder where you got your `Date` objects from and whether there could be a shortcut to getting the data before it’s becoming `Date` objects. Usage: *to parse* means to convert *from* a string. The opposite operation, which I believe you are after, is called *formatting*.

Comment: There may be some optimization possible depending on the exact data and exact format. If you’ve got a million dates that all fall within 2018, caching of the strings translated to could come into play, for example.

Comment: Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: Your code is *generating* a `String`, not *parsing*.

Comment: @Jai If the conversion is done in parallel, the OP just needs to ensure that each thread has its own format object (eg using a `ThreadLocal`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

The back-port of the *java.time* classes takes **under a microsecond** to generate a `String` from a `LocalDate` in your desired pattern.

```
String output = myLocalDate.toString() ;  // Takes less than a microsecond.
```

Using this library, I would not worry about date-time strings being a bottleneck.

## *ThreeTen-Backport*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible old date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`. For Java 6 & 7, most of that functionality is back-ported in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, using nearly identical API. Add the library and import: `import org.threeten.bp.*;`

Your example format of YYYY-MM-DD is the default used by the [`LocalDate`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDate.html) class when parsing/generating text.

Example code.

Set up a list of `LocalDate` objects.

```
long years = 1000;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate lastDate = today.plusYears( years );
int initialCapacity = ( int ) ( ( years + 1 ) * 366 );
List < LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList <>( initialCapacity );
LocalDate localDate = today;
System.out.println( "From: " + today + " to: " + lastDate );
while ( localDate.isBefore( lastDate ) ) {
    dates.add( localDate );
    // Setup next loop.
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

Run the test.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();

for ( LocalDate date : dates ) {
    String output = date.toString(); // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
}

long stop = System.nanoTime();
long elapsed = ( stop - start );
long nanosEach = elapsed / dates.size();

System.out.println( "nanosEach: " + nanosEach );
```

### Results: Under a microsecond each

When running on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013), 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, in IntelliJ 2018.3, using Java 10.0.2 from the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)-based [Zulu JVM](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/) from Azul Systems…

> When running a batch of 100 years, I get about 650 nanoseconds each. That is about two/thirds of a microsecond.
>
> When running a batch of 1,000 years, I get about 260 nanoseconds each. That is about a quarter of a microsecond.

I doubt processing date strings with this library will prove to be a bottleneck in your app’s performance.

## Thread-safety

The *java.time* classes are designed to be inherently [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), including the use of [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

You can cache a single `DateTimeFormatter` object, and use it repeatedly, even across threads.

Your desired format, defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, is pre-defined as a constant in both *java.time* and in the *ThreeTen-Backport* library: [`DateTimeFormatter .ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd" ) ;  // Or just use the pre-defined constant for that particular pattern, `DateTimeFormatter .ISO_LOCAL_DATE`, also used by default in `LocalDate::toString`.
…
String output = localDate.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

To convert many dates into string, you can use same `SimpleDateFormat`, but do it only in one thread, because `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe. But, as one of possible variant, you can create util class and hold `SimpleDateFormat` in `ThreadLocal` variable and use it anywhere.

**Slow:** `SimpleDateFormat` is been created multiple times:

```
for(Date date : hugeDateList)
    String str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
```

**Fast:** `SimpleDateFormat` is been created only once and use multiple times

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

for(Date date : hugeDateList)
    String str = df.format(date);
```

**Faster:** `SimpleDateFormat` is been declared once per thread, date list is been formatted with multiple threads (e.g. 10 threads with 10% of all dates each):

```
public final class TimeUtils {

    private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> THREAD_LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    public static String format(Date date) {
        return date != null ? THREAD_LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT.get().format(date) : null;
    }

}

// TODO this is Java8 only for example, in Java7 ther're lines to create and run threads (not related to the question)
hugeDateList.parallelStream().map(TimeUtils::format).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: OP said no Java 8 though.

Comment: @Jai see comment in `TODO`

Comment: The correct way of implementing parallelism without stream API might be the most complex part in this whole solution though.

Comment: Create couple thread and use it - is pretty simple and does not relates to the question. Correct answer is that fastest way is to use multiple threads and with only one `SDF` instance for each of them.

Comment: @Jai Answers on Stack Overflow are not written only for the asker (or it would be better to send an email message), but for everyone with similar questions now and in the future to learn from. So even though the asker is not going to use Java 8 or later just now, information on how to do that is still top relevant in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

parsing&formating are compute-intensive tasks, if your computer has multiple processors, I would suggest to make your task multi-threading.

For exmaple:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {

    Date date;

    public MyCallable(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(your pattern).format(date);
    }
}

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // thread pool
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        // your date objects
        List<Date> dates = ...

        List<Future<String>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();

        // let the thread poll run tasks
        for (Date date : dates) {
            MyCallable myCallable = new MyCallable(date);
            futureList.add(executorService.submit(myCallable));
        }

        // collect result
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Future<String> future : futureList) {
            try {
                results.add(future.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to write an answer using `ForkJoinPool`, but I guess it's a little overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

a quicker way would be not to re-create the SimpleDateFormat each time

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);  // outside loop or a field 
....
String dateString = df.format(value);
```

Comment: Better to add some tests. Make formattor singlton maybe save some space, while it does not  gurantee `faster`.

Comment: But keep in mind that the implementation of SimpleDataFormat is NOT thread-safe. Creating the instance once outside a loop is ok, but don't use the same instance in multiple threads.