# How to parse date string EEE MMM dd to yyyy-MM-dd in java

Tags: java, date, java-8

I'm having the date in this pattern **EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ**,  I would like to convert this to yyyy-MM-dd format in java, I tried below approach but I'm getting this exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:`

```
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String dateInString = "Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2017";

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: By `EEEEE` you mean `DDDDD`, right?

Comment: Parsing and formatting at two seperate steps and you will need a formatter that represents each pattern to make it work

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: First of all I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` (or `OffsetDateTime`) and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: `Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2017` is *not* in pattern `EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. It’s not in pattern `dd-MMM-yyyy` either and therefore cannot be parsed using a formatter with the latter pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From java-8 you can use the `ZonedDateTime` with pattern of your input date which is `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

```
String dateInString = "Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2017";

ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateInString,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"));
System.out.println(time.toLocalDate());   //2017-10-01
```

By default `LocalDate` is without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your formatter as the concept 'date, month, year', and then you try to ask it to parse a string that isn't in this format at all. You need to make a formatter that can format `Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2017`, and `dd-MMM-yyyy` obviously isn't it. The [javadoc of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will tell you what combination of letters you need to use.

Once you've got that, it's easy: parse with this new formatter, then call `.format` with your old one (the `dd-MMM-yyyy` one).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same formatter for both parsing and formatting. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/999191

Answer (score 0):

You double-create the DateFormat one parse and once to format

```
DateFormat dfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
DateFormat dfFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dfFormat.format(dfParse.parse("Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2017"))
```