# Parse ISO-8601 Datetime

Tags: java

It seems the proper form of timestamp to parse ISO-8601 in Java looks like:

"2020-02-03T23:40:17+00:00";

However mine looks like:

"2020-02-03T23:40:17+0000";

How can I parse this properly?

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

 public class TestTime {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String ts = "2020-02-03T23:40:17+0000";
            DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
            OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(ts, timeFormatter);
            long timestamp = offsetDateTime.toEpochSecond() * 1000;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe change your `DateTimeFormatter` to the format that you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date)

Comment: @itwasntme This doesn't work  `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssXXXX")`

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-02-03T23:40:17+0000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"))` ==> `2020-02-03T23:40:17Z`

Comment: Similar to above comment try something like `DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXX");`

Comment: Both `<time>±hh:mm` and `<time>±hhmm` are valid ISO 8601 time zone formats.  Q: Are you saying that only one format works with Java8 time?  Q: What error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: @FoggyDay While both offset formats are valid in itself, `2020-02-03T23:40:17+0000` is not as it mixes what ISO 8601 calls basic and extended format.

Comment: @Christian S. - and RFC 3399 *requires* `<time>±hh:mm` (as, apparently, does the default Java8 time parser).  Hopefully BAR has the luxury of slapping whoever gave him that `<time>±hhmm` format.  I'm curious if `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()` mitigates the problem.  I'm also curious why you suggested  `ssZZZ`.  It's not clear from your explanation, or from my understanding of ISO 8601.  Is it a "Java8 DateTimeFormatter" thing?

Comment: That doesn't have to do with ISO 8601, it's just the offset pattern that matches OP's format (see [Offset Z](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a pattern to the `DateTimeFormatter`:

```java
String ts = "2020-02-03T23:40:17+0000";
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ");
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(ts, timeFormatter);
```

---

Note that the correct pattern for the offset is `ZZZ` instead of `X` or `XXXX`, which becomes obvious when, for example, formatting the parsed date-time back to a string:

```java
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(ts, timeFormatter);
System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(timeFormatter));
```

```
2020-02-03T23:40:17Z
```

While when using `ZZZ`, it will format like `2020-02-03T23:40:17+0000`. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for `DateTimeFormatter`.