# Need to know VMS date to Long conversion

Tags: java

i am trying to find the conversion logic behind VMS date to long data type. for example in RDB database date column is timesatmp. those value passes as VMS date to long conversion.

Date value: 2008-11-13 05:10:39

response long value is : 47332698396532279

Need to know how this date is converted as long . the enoding logic should match with response value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-a-date)

Comment: no.. i need to convert these date to 17 digit long value. which means 64 bit integer

Comment: Well parse a Date, and then Date has Method getTime() which returns long value, which is milliseconds since 1.1.1970.

Comment: BTW for which timezone is this date and time?

Answer (score 0):

As michaeak wrote: The integer number shows the number of milliseconds after 01.01.1970 00:00:00.

To convert this to a 64 bit integer you need to know the resolution and base of that 64bit integer.